# Setting the cookie domain for AWS ALB OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

We've got a number of webapp testing environments that we've preivously gated with IP whitelists, but maintaining those is tedious and error-prone. For the new revision of the environment I've added an OIDC authentication rule to the ALB which has been working just fine.

However, part of the application is essentially wildcarded, unpredictable subdomains. When something regarding these subdomains requires testing the OIDC rule becomes a blocker for two reasons:

1. The ALB auth cookie is issued for the domain `dev.company.net` and will no be sent for requests against subdomains.
2. Azure's OIDC config does not allow for anything but a static list of callback URLs, so `foo.dev.company.net` causes an authentication failure.

Is there any way to specify the authentication cookie domain for the OIDC rule? Simply having the cookie domain set to `.dev.company.net` should cover this, but I can't find any relevant documentation of config options.